# .htaccess in subdirectory always refers to root

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm facing a quite strange behaviour of my .htaccess. Whenever I try to access a link rewritten by mod_rewrite, my .htaccess is refering to the root and not the subdirectory I'm working in. My folder structure looks like that:
`htdocs/
   blog6/
     .htaccess`
My .htaccess looks like that:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

ErrorDocument 401 /core/error/401.php
ErrorDocument 403 /core/error/403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /core/error/404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /core/error/500.html

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /blog6/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

But whenever I try to access a file through a rewritten url, I get a 404 error and the log says:

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/index.php' not found or unable to stat
```

So it seems like my .htaccess wants to access the file in the htdocs instead of using the subdirectory. When I write `/blog6` in my rewriteRule, everything works fine, but why RewriteBase isn't working properly? If it's important, I'm using `<base>` in my html

Comment: What URL do you open in browser that causes this 404? I believe this .htaccess is in `/blog6/` directory?

Comment: @anubhava yes, the .htaccess is in `/blog6/`. I open `http://localhost/blog6/login` which should be the rewritten form of `http://localhost/blog6/index.php?page=login`. If I put a `blog6/` in front of the rewriteRule, it looks like that: `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /blog6/index.php?page=$1 [L]` and works. And that is the point where it's confusing me, as the rewriteBase has no impact...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RewriteBase` works only if you provide **relative URL in target of `RewriteRule`** so change your code to:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

ErrorDocument 401 /core/error/401.php
ErrorDocument 403 /core/error/403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /core/error/404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /core/error/500.html

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /blog6/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```